# Connection between coordinates of surfaces

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

Let

$$dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 = E(u,v)du^2+2F(u,v)dudv+G(u,v)dv^2$$

and

$$dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 = \widetilde{E}d\widetilde{u}^2+2\widetilde{F}d\widetilde{u}d\widetilde{v}+\widetilde{G}d\widetilde{v}^2$$

Then apparently

$$\widetilde{E}=E\frac{\partial u}{\partial\widetilde{u}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\widetilde{u}}+2F\frac{\partial u}{\partial\widetilde{u}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\widetilde{u}}+G\frac{\partial v}{\partial\widetilde{u}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\widetilde{u}}$$

How has this been derived?

Comment: From https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~md384/neessnmeiwseis.pdf page 6

Comment: Use the Jacobian change-of-basis matrix.